# composite pattern, I am not able to retrieve all entities from the backend

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, fetch, composite

I am trying to implement and use the composite pattern in my system.

The problem is that I cant retrieve all the hierarchy of entities from the backend.

I am not sure what is the problem, the fetch is fine. So, I am not sure if is hibernate.

Lets see, these are my entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "game")
public class Game extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "detail")
private String detail;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "rule_id")
private GameRule gameRule;
...
```

In this class I save the main "GameRule"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game_rule")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("rule")
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "_class")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleRule.class, name = "SimpleRule"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CompositeRule.class, name = "CompositeRule") })
public abstract class GameRule implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4597791997254248990L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String operator;
```

In this class I save a list of GameRules

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("group")
public class CompositeRule extends GameRule {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6197786758476721324L;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "game_rules_hierarchy",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_rule_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_rule_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@OrderBy("id")
private List<GameRule> rules;

public List<GameRule> getRules() { return rules; }

public void setRules(List<GameRule> rules) { this.rules = rules; }
```

And now the leaf entity.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("simple")
public class SimpleRule extends GameRule {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6197786758476721324L;

private String variable;
private Double value;

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
private Device device;
```

Now, the restController to retrieve the data

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/games/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Game> getGame(@PathVariable Long id) {
   log.debug("REST request to get Game : {}", id);
   Game game = gameRepository.findOne(id);

   return Optional.ofNullable(game)
            .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(
                result,
                HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
```

Now in the view I am able to receive the CompositeRule objects but nothing  about the simpleRule objects.

From the UI (angular), I am using this JSON to load the hierarchy.

```
vm.game.gameRule = {id: null, operator: "", type:null, _class:"CompositeRule",
            rules: [ {id: null, operator: "", type:null, _class:"CompositeRule", rules:
                [{id: null, type:null, _class:"SimpleRule", device: "6", variable: "POWER", operator: ">", value: "100"},
                    {id: null, type:null, _class:"SimpleRule", device: "6", variable: "POWER", operator: ">", value: "100"}]}
            ]};
```

This is loaded succesfully in the DB. But the problem is when I try to retrieve the entire hierarchy. Currently I am receiving only the CompositeRule objects, somthing like:

```
vm.game.gameRule = {id: 1, operator: "", type:null, _class:"CompositeRule",
            rules: [ {id: 2, operator: "", type:null, _class:"CompositeRule", rules:[]} ]};]
```

In the RestController I am able to see all the hierarchy objects. I am not sure what the problem is.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

MY BAD!

Everything was fine. My problem is in the console logs. It seems that the console in chrome is not showing all the hierarchy. But if I go to the network view I am able to see everything.

Thanks.